# Matplotlib x-axis only show actual values as labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

The data that I use for my matplotlib plots are spread unevenly around the x-axis. In the example below, for instance, the x-axis values are [0.001, 0.0033, 0.0066, 0.01, 0.033, 0.066, 0.1, 0.33]. Is it possible to get the x-axis to only draw tickers and labels at those specific values, rather than show the even range between 0 and 0.35?

[image: Example plot]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using the `pyplot` interface, you can use the `pyplot.xticks` function to set the x ticks to anything you like.  So you can just do `pyplot.xticks([0.001, 0.0033, 0.0066, 0.01, 0.033, 0.066, 0.1, 0.33])`.